# Have you been riding your bike? Focus on activity?

Tags: present-perfect-progressive

What have you been doing during lock down?  Have you been riding your bike or going for walks?

Does this mean someone has ridden their bike multiple times or not necessarily? Or is the present perfect continuous used because the answer echoes the question and it just focusses on the activity of bike riding? I understand "going for walks" means multiple walks.

Comment: "How have you been occupying yourself during lockdown? Was it with bike rides or with walks?"

Comment: @Kate Bunting But if I ask "what have you been doing during lock down? "Have you been baking a cake?" it doesn't imply multiple times, correct?

Comment: No, because you said _a cake_! "Have you been baking [cakes]?" would imply (in this context) a habit rather than a single episode of baking.

Comment: @Kate Bunting But why do you interpret "have you been riding your bike" as a multiple activity? Riding a bike has a duration, even if it is just once.

Comment: "Have you been riding your bike this morning?" probably refers to a single ride. "Have you been riding your bike during lockdown?" (a period of many weeks) would be understood to imply a habit of doing so. Otherwise it would be "Well, I went for a bike ride last week." "I baked a cake for my birthday."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Otherwise it would be "Well, I went for a bike ride last week." "I baked a cake for my birthday." I don't understand, to what questions are these the answers?

Comment: "Yes, I've been riding my bike" and "Yes, I've been baking" imply that the speaker has done those things a number of times during lockdown. If they had only done so once, they wouldn't use the continuous tense.

Comment: @anouk  The key word that Kate used was 'imply' - the entire context implies multiple rides, but the question could actually be answered either way: "Yes, I've ridden every day"  or just as valid: "I've only ridden my bike once."