# What do these sentences imply?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What have you been doing this week while you have been at home?

Have you been baking or have you been washing the car? Let us know!

Do these imply multiple baking and washing sessions?

If they don't imply multiple sessions can the present perfect simple be used in this context?

Comment: These are not English questions per se.

Comment: This is very similar to your earlier question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/274387/have-you-been-riding-your-bike-focus-on-activity.

Comment: The questions neither imply nor preclude multiple sessions. Asking "Have you baked, or washed the car?" would rather suggest the activity happened only once.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I know. I wanted to know if "this week" makes a difference.compared to "during lockdown", because it is not as long a period. I would like to know your opinion on this.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian If it doesn't imply nor preclude multiple sessions, what does it imply? Is the present perfect continuous used to focus on the activity?

Comment: (I've just seen your very similar earlier question.) "What have you been doing this week/this year/during lockdown" all ask the other person to tell us about their activities: those performed more than once and those performed once only. The period doesn't matter. "What have you been doing..." is a common and colloquial formula. It DOES focus on the activity/activities. Changing the tense doesn't change the focus.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian "Have you been riding your bike during lockdown?" (a period of many weeks) would be understood to imply a habit of doing so. This is what Kate said, but you are saying it doesn't imply or preclude multiple sessions.

Comment: It depends whether you think it likely that a person would wash their car several times in a week! If I asked someone "Have you been baking this week?", and I knew they were a keen cook, I wouldn't be _surprised_ if they had had more than one session. That's all that can be said.

Comment: "This is what Kate said" - but I also said that the person might reply that they had ridden their bike only once.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting If I don't expect someone to wash their car several times a week, can I still ask: "Have you been washing your car this week?" That is what I would like to know.

Comment: In that case you would be more likely to ask "Have you washed your car this week?"

Comment: @Kate BuntingDoes the same apply to "Have you been baking this week?" Because old brixtonian said the questions neither imply nor preclude multiple sessions. I am confused.

Comment: I answered that in my last comment but one.

Comment: @Kate Bunting So basically "have you been baking this week?" doesn't say anything about the number of baking sessions.